# Как сделано население в SimCity 4 и Cities: SkyLine - это 100к объектов?

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Все видели в SimCity и Cities:Skyline и подобных им, что в городе можно клацнуть по пешеходу / машине и вам высветится интерфейс, в котором есть: **Имя персонажа**, **место жительства**, **место работы** и **куда он направляется**.
Насколько я понимаю, эти жители, просто объекты одного, а может и нескольких классов, и создать такое же не тяжело. А когда города под 100к человек??.. Так вот вопрос к опытным программистам: мне кажется это очень "тяжелая" для ресурсов ноша. 100к + объектов? и нормальные системные требования? быть не может..
В чем подвох? Или лучше сказать моя недальновидность.

Comment: Не обязательно держать все объекты в памяти, их можно подгружать динамически: например, при переходе между локациями выгружать старые данные и забирать новые. При выборе персонажа по уникальному идентификатору можно подгрузить все остальные данные (фио, место работы и т.д.). Также часть персонажей появляется и затем пропадает (например, дошел до пункта назначения), не все 100к одновременно на экране.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. То, что в городе 100к объектов, не значит, что создаются объекты для них всех.
2. 100к объектов, которые, скажем, весят по 200 байт - это 20 мегабайт. Вместится. Проблемы, правда, будут с GC, скорей всего. Но, думаю, можно настройки generations подкрутить так, чтоб не было больших фризов при сборке.

По существу же, сомнительно, что все 100к объектов всегда в памяти. Я как минимум несколько способов вижу оптимизации:

1. **Разбиение на зоны/локации.** Грузить объекты только в рамках этой зоны. Вспомните старые игры, при переходах между локациями было окно загрузки. Если мне память не изменяет, то в той же WoW'ке в своё время при переходах между локациями оно было. Это сейчас уже они оптимизировали, что не приходится ждать и создаётся иллюзия бесшовного мира.
2. **Использовать пулы объектов.** Чтоб не грузить лишний раз GC, да и просто, чтоб не тратить ресурсы на создание объектов, используются пулы. Скажем, изначально создать пул из 100 объектов-пустышек. По мере надобности заполнять их свойства нужными данными (когда человек/здание/машина в зоне видимости). Когда объект выходит из зоны видимости, очищать объект и запихивать назад в пул. Потом этот объект из пула уже возьмёт другой персонаж игрового мира. Я такие пулы использовал для объектов, которые часто создаются: пули, заклинания и т.п.

   Я могу привести код из текущего нашего проекта. Я там использую `org.apache.commons.pool2` для создания пула подключений к базе данных:

   Например, метод, который грузит мета данные для сервиса из базы:

   ```
   public void loadMetaInfo(){
       LOG.debug("load meta info");
       DB db = null;
       try{
           db = mDB.getResource(); // получаем подключение из пула
           String reqId =  getRequestId();
           db.send(new CommandRequest(Command.INFO.toString(), reqId), this);
           mRequests.put(reqId, new CacheItem("load info"));
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
           LOG.error("loadMetaInfo: db_problem");
       }
       finally{
           if(db != null)
               db.close();  // после окончания работы возвращаем объект в пул, 
                            // чтоб им могли воспользоваться другие клиенты
       }
   }
   ```
3. Как заметили в комментариях, для оптимизация работы с памятью можно предотвращать создание экземпляров классов, имеющих общую сущность, используя **паттерн Приспособленец** (Flyweight pattern). Почитать про него (да и про многие другие паттерны) можно на [этом](http://dofactory.com/net/flyweight-design-pattern) сайте. По сути, это похоже на п.2. Типичный пример использования этого шаблона - Buffer pools.

### **Паттерн Приспособленец (Flyweight)**

Это *структурный* шаблон проектирования, позволяющий использовать разделяемые объекты сразу в нескольких контекстах. Данный паттерн используется преимущественно для оптимизации работы с памятью.

Скажем, если мы хотим написать редактор текстовый. Для простоты положим, что используются только буквы русского алфавита. Создавать объект на каждую букву - накладно очень. Можно определить словарь, состоящий из 33 объектов, которые мы будет переиспользовать. В итоге, к примеру, для текста из 330 букв мы уменьшили число создаваемых объектов в 10 раз. Если речь о книге, то там речь уже на тысячи идёт.

Ключевым моментом является разделение состояния на внутренне и внешнее. Внутреннее состояние от контекста не зависит. В примере с символами внутреннее состояние описывается кодом символа из таблицы кодировки. Так как внутреннее состояние не зависит от контекста, то оно может быть разделяемым и поэтому выносится в разделяемые объекты.

Внешнее состояние зависит от контекста и является изменчивым. В применении к символам внешнее состояние может представлять положение символа на странице (строка + колонка). То есть код символа может быть использован многими символами, тогда как положение на странице будет для каждого символа индивидуально.

**Применительно к вашему вопросу.** У каждого объекта внутренним состоянием может задаваться размер объекта, его материал, какие-то физические величины, параметры коллайдера. Внешнее же состояние: имя персонажа, место жительства, место работы и куда он направляется.

Можно показать принцип работы UML диаграммой с Wiki:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Применительно к вашему вопросу накидаю по-быстрому примерную реализацию на Java. Проверить код сейчас нет возможности, но, как мне кажется, главное - уловить суть.

Скажем, у нас персонажи двух типов: толстые и худые. Тогда будет что-то такое.

Базовый класс, определяющий объект-персонаж:

```
public abstract  class Character{

    protected String mTitle;

    protected String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    protected void setTitle(String mTitle) {
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
    }

    protected int getWidth() {
        return mWidth;
    }

    protected void setWidth(int mWidth) {
        this.mWidth = mWidth;
    }

    protected int getHeight() {
        return wHeight;
    }

    protected void setHeight(int wHeight) {
        this.wHeight = wHeight;
    }

    protected int mWidth;

    protected int wHeight;

    public abstract void printCharacter();      
}
```

Две его реализации:

```
public class FatCharacter extends Character {

    public FatCharacter(){
        setTitle("Я толстяк");
        setWidth(20);
        setHeight(40);
    }


    @Override
    public void printCharacter() {
        System.out.println("Title: " + getTitle() + ", width:" + getWidth() + ", height: " + getHeight());
    }

}

public class ThinCharacter extends Character {

    public ThinCharacter(){
        setTitle("Я худой");
        setWidth(10);
        setHeight(40);
    }

    @Override
    public void printCharacter() {
        System.out.println("Title: " + getTitle() + ", width:" + getWidth() + ", height: " + getHeight());
    }

}
```

Фабрика, собственно, которая отвечает за создание объектов:

```
public class FlyweightFactory {

    public static enum Code{ Thin, Fat};

    private Map<Code, Character> mCharacters = new EnumMap<Code, Character>(Code.class);

    public Character getCharacter(Code characterCode){
        Character character = mCharacters.get(characterCode);

        // если такого объекта ещё нету, то создаём
        if (character == null){
            switch (characterCode){
                case Fat : 
                    character = new FatCharacter();
                    break;
                case Thin : 
                    character = new ThinCharacter();
                    break;  
            }

            // добавляем в пул
            mCharacters.put(characterCode, character);
        }
        return character;
    } 

}
```

Использовать так:

```
Character character = factory.getCharacter(Code.Fat);
character.printCharacter();
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вы забыли упомянуть шаблон _Приспособленец_ (_Flyweight_) =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev написал лишь о том, что сразу в голову пришло)

Comment: Даёшь про шаблон Приспособленец (Flyweight)! =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну, кратко написал. Подробное описание слишком много места займёт. Тогда придётся и все остальные пункты увеличить по размеру, чтоб соотносились по важности нормально друг к другу.

Comment: @Suvitruf, если вам не лень, то можно просто в отдельный ответ вынести)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб как будет время, может распишу все пункты поподробнее. Сейчас на работе)

Comment: @Suvitruf, будем ждать) Тема интересная)

Comment: @Suvitruf Отличный ответ, спасибо)) про пул объектов вообще в тему :)) информация очень кстати, буду признателен если и про приспособленца распишешь, хотя бы так же абстрактно :).
А вообще интересно - человек, разбирающийся в программировании, на работе в такую ночь..)) что же за такая работа?

Comment: @OgneFF я нынче в Сан-Франциско обитаю. У меня сейчас 4 часа дня )

Comment: @OgneFF в общем обновил часть, касающуюся именно этого шаблона применительно к вопросу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил текст про шаблон (:

Comment: @Suvitruf Спасибо :) очень хороший ответ, всё грамотно, последовательно, с примерами.

Comment: @OgneFF рад был помочь )

Comment: Немного позанудствую, 100к объектов по 200 байт это 20 мегабайт, вполне в памяти поместится )

Comment: @Russtam обсчитался я на пару порядков =D

Comment: @Suvitruf отличный вопрос-ответ! (+)